# How to start zookeeper ensemble using Curator TestingServer

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing, apache-curator

I am just trying to start a zookeeper ensemble (Leader - follower) with java implementation using the [Curator frame work](https://curator.apache.org/) or [zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.6/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html).

Initially i have checked with binary mode and it was working fine with example configs shown below.

**zoo.cfg**

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
```

and **myid** files created accordingly and the zookeeper ensemble created as i expected (Leader - Followers created).

```
Connections: 4
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x30000052a
Mode: leader
Node count: 158
Proposal sizes last/min/max: 146/36/1471
```

When i tried to achieve the same using **org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig** configs with Classes,

**org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain**

```
ZooKeeperServerMain zkServer = new ZooKeeperServerMain();
        final ServerConfig configuration = new ServerConfig();
        configuration.readFrom(peerConfig);
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                zkServer.runFromConfig(configuration);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("ZooKeeper Failed", e);
            }
        }).start();
```

**org.apache.curator.test.TestingServer**

```
InstanceSpec spec = new InstanceSpec(zkDataDir, clientPort, electionPort, -1, true, serverId, tickTime, maxClientCnxns, customProperties);

zkServer = new TestingServer(spec, true);
```

Both starts zookeeper in stand alone mode and it seems both the implementations not care about the configuration **server.1=..... server.2=.... server.3=.....**.

**What i am missing here ? how to start a zookeeper using java in leader follower mode ?**

**Note:** I am newbie with zookeeper related stuffs and docs still confusing me. Please guide me for the same.. Thanks... :)

Answer (score 0):

Curator TestingServer can be treated as regular ZooKeeper server. As such, leader-follower can be tested with it, using Curator LeaderLatch for example.

[Leader-follower unit test example](https://github.com/CiscoSE/commons-cluster/blob/main/commons-cluster/src/test/java/com/cisco/commons/cluster/controller/ClusterControllerTest.java#L44)

[Leader-follower implementation example](https://github.com/CiscoSE/commons-cluster/blob/main/commons-cluster/src/main/java/com/cisco/commons/cluster/controller/ClusterController.java#L213)

Note: I am the author of this project.